# Finding the limits to calculate the surface integral of a tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1$)

Tags: calculus

There is the tetrahedron $OABC$, where $O(0,0,0)$, $A(1,0,0)$, $B(0,1,0)$, $C(0,0,1)$. I would appreciate your guidance to find the limits of $z$, in order to calculate the surface integral through Gauss theorem.

I have already found the limits of $x$ and $y$.  I have already found $\operatorname{div} f(x,y,z) = 6y$.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: It is a surface integral and we need the limits of z.

Comment: You want to calculate surface area of tetrahedron? What are the computed lengths of OA,OB and OC you obtained?

Comment: @Vasilis If it's a surface integral it's not a triple integral, it's a double integral (or rather four double integrals, one for each face)

Comment: Correct. It is a surface integral and we are asked to calculate through Gauss theorem.

Comment: The tetrahedron is bounded by several planes. Can you find the equation of each one? Two of them will give you natural choices for the limits of $z$.

Comment: I have found x+y=1, x+z=1, y+z=1, x+y+z=1. Is that correct?

Comment: No, $ x=0,y=0,z=0,x+y+z= 1$

Comment: I see. So it is: 0<z<1-x-y, 0<y<1-x and 0<x<1 as the limits of x,y,z in the triple integral?

Comment: @Vasilis That's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!